# Rewrite url not working in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have website. I just want to rewrite url using `.htaccess`
Here is the code which I want to rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /search_data.php\?keywords=([^&]+)&f=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule  ^/search_data.php/?$  /search/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]
```

this the current url

```
http://localhost/mywbsite/search_data.php?keywords=one+piece&f=149
```

I want to convert this to this

```
http://localhost/mywbsite/search/one-piece/149
```

I tried above code but its not working please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QUERY_STRING` is only used to match query string without URI.

You need to use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywbsite/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search_data\.php\?keywords=([^&]+)&f=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search_data.php?keywords=$1&f=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: hey hi its work but problem is its removing my folder name also from url also after this code my url is http://localhost/search/one+piece/149

Comment: i mean after your htaccess code my new url is localhost/search/one+piece/149 and and i want url like this http://localhost/mywbsite/search/one-piece/149 above code removing mywbsite i.e. my project name

Comment: thax it work for me i can't give you 1 up i don't have enough reputation sory

Comment: No issues, accepting the answer is more than enough. Though you have 15+ reps now :)

Comment: hey hi after this code page is properly redirect but the problem is css, js and image loading like this localhost/search/one+piece/149/styles/metro_blue/theme/large.css

Comment: You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/mywbsite/" />`

Comment: ya i solve that  problem now looking for instead of +(plus) sign i want -(dash) sign i mean before (one+piece) after rewrite (one-piece)

Comment: do you have any tutorials where i can learn how to write .htacces file

Comment: i did't find anything please help me how to remove +(plus) sign and put (-)dash sign

Comment: You can learn about .htaccess on http://askapache.com and consider opening a new question for `+/-` sign removal. Adding question via comment is not a good practice on SO